# Good pattern to distribute sqlite databases on a update cycle

Tags: android, sqlite, auto-update

I have an Android app that uses a number of sqlite3 databases. They are bundled with the app initially but then must be updated/downloaded periodically (approx 28 days) from a server. i.e databases expire and must be replaced with entirely new copy of the database (please don't suggest how to do incremental update etc. - its not possible. entire database must be downloaded again.)

My app only reads from the databases. User may be run the app with a given version of database until it expires. After that a red warning is shown. They go to download page in the app where they are shown updated database versions to download. Download with overwrite the local copy, update its version number and use it as if its new database. My question is:

How do I maintaining versioning in this scenario ? i.e.  do I keep a text file/a separate small sqlite database of just the version number on the server for "current" databases ? (I don't want to unnecessarily download the entire database until a new version has been issued) How to keep keep version of local database ? In another local database table ?

What if I have N databases like this in my app ?

Basically whats a god way to distribute N databases with their own separate version numbers on different update cycle ?

Comment: **How to keep keep version of local database ? In another local database table ?** -- If you have a table maintained separately for the database updates then just add a version column and whenever you ask for updates and get a new copy of database update the versions in that table

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I was thinking.